# Facebook Redirect url in ruby on rails open ssl error

Tags: ruby, facebook, omniauth

I have followed the omniauth devise facebook app as explained by Ryan in episode 235.After the user authorizes we are getting the error at http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback?code=13444...

The following are the facebook settings :
 App Domain : localhost
    siteurl: locahost:3000/
    canvas url: http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/

please tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: Please post exact details of the error message which you are getting, including the full backtrace if there is one. Also post the relevant parts of the code you are using. This way, someone may be able to help you.

Comment: The following error message i am getting:  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
certificate verify failed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In one project, we had to add this code to `config/environments/development.rb` to get Facebook connect working for local development:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Comment: Thank you mate!! you are amazing, you have saved us from getting squeezed up!! Cheers!!

Comment: Glad you like the answer. If it was useful for you, an upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: solved my problem on Win 7. Thanks Alex D. I had spent near 6 hours to get this solution.

Comment: Solved my problem @ mac