# Omniauth Facebook Error - Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed

Tags: facebook, omniauth, faraday-oauth

(FYI: I'm following the Twitter Omniauth from railscast #241. I used Twitter successfully, now going onto Facebook)

As soon as I logged into Facebook using Omniauth, I get this error:

```
Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

What does this mean?

This is my code

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, '<key from fb>', '<another key from fb>'
end
```

There's actually nothing much in my code, all I have is in the sessionController that I want to use to_yaml to see what's inside the request.env

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
    end
end
```

How do I solve the Faraday error?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are getting this error because Ruby cannot find a root certificate to trust.

Fix for Windows: https://gist.github.com/867550

Fix for Apple/Linux: http://martinottenwaelter.fr/2010/12/ruby19-and-the-ssl-error/ <--This site is now down.

**Here is the Apple/Linux fix according the site above:**

The solution is to install the curl-ca-bundle port which contains the same root certificates used by Firefox:

```
sudo port install curl-ca-bundle
```

and tell your https object to use it:

```
https.ca_file = '/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt'
```

Note that if you want your code to run on Ubuntu, you need to set the ca_path attribute instead, with the default certificates location /etc/ssl/certs.

In the end, that’s what will work on both Mac OS X and Ubuntu:

```
require 'net/https'
https = Net::HTTP.new('encrypted.google.com', 443)
https.use_ssl = true
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
https.ca_path = '/etc/ssl/certs' if File.exists?('/etc/ssl/certs') # Ubuntu
https.ca_file = '/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt' if File.exists('/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt') # Mac OS X
https.request_get('/')
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer came in at the right time as I was on a 1 week holiday. Thanks!

Comment: That site must have just went down.  I added the google cached version.

Comment: "tell your https object to use it:" Can you elaborate on this? Should I put the given lines of code in a .rb file somewhere in my Rails app? Where?

Comment: @NeilHoff can you elaborate on GeorgMillo's question?

Comment: @GeorgeMillo this worked for me, export env variable for openssl (ruby 2, rails 4): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728436/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-c

Comment: You can also `brew install curl-ca-bundle`

Answer (score 63):

I've fixed this on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 with this solution:

```
$ rvm remove 1.9.3 (or whatever version of ruby you are using)
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

after this you will need to download the missing cacert.pem file:

```
$ cd $rvm_path/usr/ssl
$ sudo curl -O http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
$ sudo mv cacert.pem cert.pem
```

Comment: thank you! I tried a bunch of solutions but this is what it took to make it work locally for me.

Comment: Yes, this worked much better for me, as I'm not using 'port' - thanks!

Comment: very useful. worked well for 10.8.2  with Rails, devise and google oauth

Comment: Re-installing the ruby works till the compiling step. Then I get:

    Error running 'make', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/make.log
    There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

Comment: As indicated in the answer below, you should reference this post from the Rails Project: http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Comment: I saw `Beware, 'rvm pkg ...' is deprecated, read about the new autolibs feature: 'rvm help autolibs'.` when running on Ubuntu 13. How would your helpful instructions change using `rvm autolibs ...`?

Comment: tried this in 2015, this solution ended up fixing it for me http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html#comment-657918573

Answer (score 21):

Andrei's answer didn't work for me on Mac OSX 10.8.3. I had reinstalled openssl to install ruby 2.0 some time ago and since then always got this error. I fixed it thanks to Andrei's answer and [instructions from the Rails project](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html).

I ran:

```
$ rvm -v
$ rvm get head
# Installation of latest version of rvm...
$ rvm -v
# rvm 1.19.5 (master)
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
# Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Old.
# Certificates for /Users/mpapis/.sm/pkg/versions/openssl/0.9.8x/ssl/cert.pem: Old.
$ sudo rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
# Updating certificates...
```

Then I checked if the certificates were correctly updated by running `rvm osx-ssl-certs status all` again but `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` was still not updated. I don't know if that was necessary but I did the following:

```
$ cd /usr/local/etc/openssl/
$ curl -O http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
$ mv cacert.pem cert.pem
```

After that the problem was fixed. Hope that helps someone else who runs into the same issue.

Comment: I have sent this answer to 5 people and it always solves the issue! You da man!

Answer (score 8):

this worked for me (on Mac OS X):

```
$ brew install curl-ca-bundle
$ export SSL_CERT_FILE=/usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/share/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: this worked for me too on OSx 10.8.5, none of the other solutions here worked, only this one, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative Solution:**

[I am Win7 user with manual install the Ruby and Ruby on Rails]

I have the same problem but cannot resolve by the answer that given by this question. By the way, finally, I got problem solved by following url

[Facebook Redirect url in ruby on rails open ssl error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095755/facebook-redirect-url-in-ruby-on-rails-open-ssl-error)
  https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/wiki/Setting-up-SSL-certificates

Answer (score 3):

The RVM website suggests running `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`

[RVM Website: How to fix broken certificates in your operating system.](https://rvm.io/support/fixing-broken-ssl-certificates)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7: the above solution link of Neil Hoff (Fix for Windows: https://gist.github.com/867550) did not work for me.

Here is what works:

Using cmd.exe:

```
curl -o c:\cacert.pem http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
set SSL_CERT_FILE=c:\cacert.pem
```

using msysgit bash:

```
curl -o /c/cacert.pem http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/c/cacert.pem
```

If you do not have curl on your windows 7 command line get it here:
http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/#downloads

original solution is from here - credit to:
https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/106

Dunn.

Answer (score 0):

Andrei's answer worked for me, however I ran into a huge roadblock when trying to reinstall Ruby 1.9.3.  Because I had installed a new version of Xcode since installing 1.9.3 I was unable to reinstall until I opened the Xcode Preferences and installed the Command Line Tools from the Downloads tab.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [certified](https://github.com/stevegraham/certified) gem. Description:

> Ensure net/https uses OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER to verify SSL
>   certificates and provides certificate bundle in case OpenSSL cannot
>   find one