# Getting Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed when connecting from heroku rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, heroku, faraday, faraday-oauth

My company has a simple oauth server at https://auth.vitalvu.com

I'm developing a rails app that needs to make requests to that server (via the omniauth-oauth2 gem). When I try to run the app on Heroku I get the error:

`Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

I've tested it as [described here](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/wiki/Setting-up-SSL-certificates).

From the app's `rails console` on my local machine

```
connection = Faraday::Connection.new 'https://auth.vitalvu.com'
connection.get '/ping.json'
```

works just fine.

However, after pushing the app to Heroku, `heroku run rails console`

```
connection = Faraday::Connection.new 'https://auth.vitalvu.com'
connection.get '/ping.json'
```

results in the faraday error and

```
connection = Faraday::Connection.new 'https://auth.vitalvu.com', :ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}
connection.get '/ping.json'
```

results in the faraday error and

```
connection = Faraday::Connection.new 'https://auth.vitalvu.com', :ssl => {:ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs"}
connection.get '/ping.json'
```

results in the faraday error

I'm not sure what else to try. Suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775640/omniauth-facebook-error-faradayerrorconnectionfailed

Comment: esjd, thanks for the link, it turned out the solution was along those lines.

Comment: @phaedryx can you let us know what the solution was, exactly?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I run `heroku restart` three times - and than finally is starts to work.