# How to load openssl via rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openssl

I used the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775640/omniauth-facebook-error-faradayerrorconnectionfailed) written by Radulescu to install openssl with ruby 1.9.3-p194. Then, I'm trying to require openssl, but I've got false return. Why?

```
bla git:(master) rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.6)
[1] pry(main)> require 'openssl'
=> false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simply means the library has already been loaded.  If you try typing `OpenSSL`, you'll see it's in your namespace.

By comparison, if you try to load a library that doesn't exist, you'll get an exception:

```
1.9.3p327 :003 > require 'does-not-exist'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- does-not-exist
```

Comment: Hahahaha.. I was wasting my time looking for a solution and it was already done. Thank you!

Comment: The [`require` docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require) also explain when it would return false. `Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the feature is already loaded.`