# Octokit gem doesn't work with openssl

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openssl, pry

I'm using `octokit` gem to interact with the `github` API. So when I try via `pry` console a simple test like:

```
require 'octokit'
=> true
Octokit.user "ricardobond"
```

The console brings to me:

```
Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:917:in `connect'
```

I'm using:

OSX 10.8.4

RVM 1.19.1

Ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

Rubygems 2.0.3

OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013 (Installed via Homebrew)

---

Any tips about how can I fix that error?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a duplicate of [Omniauth Facebook Error - Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775640/omniauth-facebook-error-faradayerrorconnectionfailed) - Not the same API, but the same SSL problem :)

Comment: Which version of Octokit are you using? If this is from 2 months ago I'm guessing pre-2.*? Simply run `Octokit::VERSION` to find out.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported on the official Issues page in the Octokit project, and resolved. Have a look at issue [#262](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/issues/262), more specifically the [second to last comment](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/issues/262#issuecomment-19472481).