# Rails SSL certificate issue + mysterious "curl: Remote file name has no length!" from RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, ssl, rvm

My rails app seems to be running up until it receives the OAuth callback from Soundcloud. At that very moment, I get:

```
Faraday::SSLError
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

So I tried to update the ssl certificates on my mac using rvm:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

But I get the following strange result:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all 
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
Updating certificates for /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem: Already are up to date.
Updating certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Already are up to date.
Updating certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Already are up to date.
```

I guess certs download fail because the error remains.

I may found the start of a solution in the section "curl failing, 'curl is' ?!" of [RVM troobleshooting page](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting), but I don't understand how to apply it.

Why does curl display this message? Do anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Solved the Faraday::SSLError thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775640/omniauth-facebook-error-faradayerrorconnectionfailed#answer-11041204 but the `curl: Remote file name has no length!` warning remains...

Answer (score 0):

Solve thanks to https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2861

To solve it: `rvm get head`